# How to configure prettier (VS Code) to align the colons in an object literal to center in a single column

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax, prettier

title says it all, here's an [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2u14vc7q613vdxx/Screen%20Shot%202020-10-13%20at%201.12.30%20PM.png?dl=0). Also, is this preferred in most workflows? I just think it looks pretty. Thanks!

Comment: fyi: [open issue on github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11865)

Answer (score 2):

See [Handle block scoped alignement formatting #188](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/188), which is similar to / duplicated by [#350](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/350), [#1622](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/1622), [#3062](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3062), and [#3310](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3310). The response from the maintainers is:

> Not going to do this, sorry. It would require a lot more complexity, and I think this style fails in some cases where you have a really long variable name and it doesn't make sense to push everything over. This is an arbitrary style and we're going to stick with a consistent `var variable = value`.
>
> It technically would be very hard, just to expand. What do you do when a comment separates a group of variables? We interleave the comments after printing the nodes, so we have no knowledge of where comments are places while printing variables.

If you're going to write a reply to the maintainers, please be respectful, and please actually try to engage in constructive design discussion instead of piling on disgruntled comments. Constructive design discussion means actually trying to understand what makes solving the problem difficult (like what is mentioned in the above quote), and talking about ways to address those issues.

Also related: [auto align colons in object literals, variables, and equals like WebStorm #11865](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11865)